# Sending SMS in iPhone without redirecting to Messages app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, message, ios8

I am wondering whether it is possible to send an SMS in iPhone, without redirecting to the Messages app. 
In the app, the user should be able to input text and hit a button inside the app without redirecting to the Messages app.
If this is possible, I would very much appreciate assistance on how to do it.

Thank you,

Dean

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Not possible in iOS, you must use the Apple defined view controllers and methods in order to do this kind of stuff, this is to keep apps in a sandbox which increases security.

The best you can do is capture the users text input and then supply that to the Apple provided message view controller.

As per the comments to this answer, you could also pull up an MFMessageComposeViewController and let the user input and send the message within this controller inside of your app.

Comment: This answer is very misleading. It is possible. Just use the `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

Comment: Yes you could use that or even share sheet, I think OP wants to have full control of the message sending process which is not possible, I will update the answer to include MFMessageComposeViewController.